# Why SBT ask Username and Password

Tags: sbt

I just started to learn SBT (https://www.scala-sbt.org).
When I tried the command "sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8" in https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Hello.html. It downloaded lots of jar files, and then start to ask me to provide Username and Password.

What are the Username and Password for?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I mistyped the name of the template in sbt, that is

The following requests user & password:

```
sbt new scala/hellow-world.g8
```

But the following doesn't:

```
sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

Comment: I had the same issue with 
`sbt new scala/scala.g8` it should have been `sbt new scala/scala3.g8`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.lightbend.com/legal/licenses

*Use of the Lightbend Platform and/or ConductR in development requires acceptance of the terms outlined in the Lightbend Subscription Agreement.*

Production deployment of the Lightbend Platform requires the purchase of a Lightbend Subscription and acceptance of the terms outlined in the Lightbend Subscription Agreement.

Maybe you want learn Scala Programming Language.
https://www.scala-lang.org/

Comment: It was asked me to provide username and password to access github. Is it the same with what you said?